# Debugging Windows 7 system that has lost ability to enter Sleep state on its own

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

I have read articles here and elsewhere looking for the root cause of this problem. The system is a Win7/32 desktop used as a media center. The application is SageTV. The system has been running and operating fine for several years, and has always automatically gone to sleep. It is configured to enter sleep mode after 40 minutes of inactivity. 
About a month ago, it stopped going to sleep except by manual initiation. When it is awake, it remains awake.

The system will always enter sleep normally when manually initiated from the start menu. It always wakes normally at the time set by SageTV in the timers.

The SageTV program has not been updated for about a year. Nothing about it has changed since this problem started.

I am familiar with the POWERCFG utility. "POWERCFG -requests" returns:

```
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
None.

AWAYMODE:
None.
```

Things I have tried that have not fixed the problem:

- Reboot computer
- Verify no files on remote computers are open, and no remote computer has files open here.
- Removed every non-essential startup program (even though it used to sleep with them running)
- Re-set parameters of power plan.
- Create new power plan.
- Stop/start print spooler.
- Verify desktop theme is saved.
- Turn off media sharing and disable media sharing service.

Is there any setting or fix that I have missed?

Is there any "deeper" technique for understanding why the system is not sleeping? I'm able to write a utility to access the Windows API, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: So you are saying that the system has been able to sleep for the past year *and* you have been running SageTV in that same time? Or, is SageTV new? Most media (video, TV, etc.) programs have a setting to disable power-management because it would be silly if you sat there not touching the mouse or keyboard for two hours while watching a movie, then suddenly it turns off after 30 minutes. Check SageTV's options to see if there is a power-management related setting.

Comment: Yes, the system has been able to sleep, and it has been running SageTV in the same configuration for several years. SageTV has been discontinued, so there have been no updates for at least a year. Yes, SageTV does set the power management state properly - I can see it in "POWERCFG -requests" when playing or recording. But it removes that request when idle. Previously the system would sleep. now it does not.

Comment: Ah, nice; so SageTV is intelligent (sadly I am *still* waiting for VLC to re-enable power-management when the video is paused). Hmmm, so something, somewhere must have changed. Can you pinpoint the time when it stopped working? Perhaps there was a Windows Update just before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root cause of the problem. In SageTV, we had added a folder on a server as a source for photos to be shown in the SageTV system. Even though the system is idle and not accessing files, apparently having an application open a folder on a server is enough to permanently inhibit sleep.

It is possible to leave an explorer window open on a server, and it will still allow the system to sleep.

IHMO, this points to a Windows issue, because "POWERCFG -requests" does not report this as a condition that prevents sleep.

Also, my second question is still relevant. Is there any more capable program or utility that can reveal things about the power state that POWERCFG fails to report?